# how can i send a list of tuples from the server to the client using sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, send

I have a list of tuples that I don't know the  length of (I selected it from a sqlite3 database table).

how can I send this list from the server to a client using sockets so that the client could access the values of the list and the tuples and use them? All tuples contain 4 string values.

```
data = [("cooking","josh", "recepie", "cookies") , 
       ("fashion", "jessica", "shopping", "dresses"),
       ("sport", "jake", "basketball", "kobe bryant")]
```

Comment: You need to serialize the data and potentially put it in a message wrapper that lets the other end know how to unbuffer the data. One option is json for serialization and zeromq to package as a message. Another option is to use python's XMLRPC, a mini http server and, well, a zillion other options.

Comment: @tdelaney how can I use JSON to do that?